# Accept only future time from a time picker dialog: Android

Tags: android, timepicker

Is it possible to get only future time from a`TimePickerDialog`?

Or can I set starting time for `TimePicker` in a `TimePickerDialog`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a `Date` object e check from the TimePiker content and use  [Date.after](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after%28java.util.Date%29)  or [Date.before](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before%28java.util.Date%29)

Answer (score 0):

You have to control it from UI thread only.
Sample code.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
if (df.parse(selected_time).before(df.parse(current_time))) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select future time",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                      
}else if (df.parse(selected_time).equals(df.parse(current_time))) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select future time",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                      
}
```

I hope this will help you. If any exception or doubt please let me know.